# Write the differential equation as a first order ode on the form $\frac{d}{dt}\mathbf{y}(t)=\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{y}).$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> The motion of a harmonic ocilator $x(t)$ is described by the
>   differential equation
>
> $$\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}=-\frac{k}{m}x-\frac{c}{m}\frac{dx}{dt}$$
>
> Write the differential equation as a first order ode on the form
>   $\frac{d}{dt}\mathbf{y}(t)=\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{y}).$

I'm confused by the notation $\frac{d}{dt}\mathbf{y}(t)=\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{y}).$ The function $\mathbf{f},$ is it the same as a transofmrationmatrix, say $A$ so that the form is equivalent to $\mathbf{y}'=A\mathbf{y}?$ If this is ineed the case, then here is my try:

Let $\mathbf y=(y_1,y_2)^T$. Then we have that

$$\frac{d}{dt}\begin{bmatrix}y_1 \\ y_2\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 \\ -\frac{k}{m} & -\frac{c}{m}\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}y_1 \\ y_2\end{bmatrix}.$$

The exam solutions just say

$$\frac{d}{dt}\begin{bmatrix}x \\ v \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}v \\ -\frac{k}{m}x-\frac{c}{m}v\end{bmatrix}.$$

**Questions:**

1. What are they doing?
2. Is my answer wrong?
3. What is a good step-by-step algorithm to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is equivalent to the second one. If you rename your variables $y_1=x$ and $y_2=v$ and carry out the matrix vector multiplication you arrive at their solution, i.e. 
$$\frac{d}{dt}\begin{bmatrix}x \\ v\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 \\ -\frac{k}{m} & -\frac{c}{m}\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x \\ v\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}0 & v \\ -\frac{k}{m} x & -\frac{c}{m} v\end{bmatrix}.$$

A general difference is, that there exists always a first order equation of the form $\frac{d\mathbf{y}}{dt}(t)=\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{y}(t))$, but maybe not a linear one.

For example the nonlinear second order ode
$$ \frac{d^2}{dt^2} x = x^2,$$
can be reduced to a nonlinear first order system using $\mathbf{y} = \begin{bmatrix}x\\v\end{bmatrix}$,
$$ \frac{d}{dt} \begin{bmatrix}x\\v\end{bmatrix} = \frac{d \mathbf{y}}{dt}(t) = \mathbf{f}(\mathbf{y}(t)) = \begin{bmatrix}v\\x^2\end{bmatrix}.$$

But since $\mathbf{f}$ is nonlinear, there is no matrix $A$ independent of $x,v$ which allows a reduction to a linear first order ode of the form $\frac{d \mathbf{y}}{dt}(t) = A \cdot \mathbf{y}(t).$

The general formula for higher order differential equations can be found on wikipedia ([Reduction to first order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_differential_equation#Reduction_to_a_first-order_system)) The idea is the same: Shift the last $n-1$ on entry towards the top and replace the last line of $\mathbf{f}$ by the original right hand side.

Comment: How do I see that $v=x'?$

Comment: I assume you want to ask, why $x' = v$ holds true (not the other way around). That's the main idea behind this reduction: You just introduce the variable $v$ to be equal to $x'$. Since you introduce $v$ as a new variable, you have the freedom to do so!
And the you replace all places where $x'$ occurs with $v$.

Comment: I'm introducing the vector $\mathbf y= (x,v)^T.$ Should I also add "such that $v=x'?$

Comment: From my point of view, you don't need to mention it, because the first line of you first order system states exactly $x' = v$. (But I don't know the formal criteria you have to satisfy in the exam.)

Answer (score 1):

your answer is correct too.

Consider
$$
\begin{cases}
\dot x =v \\
\dot v = -\frac kmx-\frac cm v
\end {cases}
$$
With matrix notation 
$$
\begin{cases}
\pmatrix {\dot x \\ \dot v} =\pmatrix {0 & 1\\
 -\frac km & -\frac cm } \pmatrix {x \\ v}
\end {cases}
$$
$$
\implies
\pmatrix {\dot x \\ \dot v} =\pmatrix {v\\
 -\frac kmx -\frac cmv } 
$$

Comment: How do I see that $v=x'?$

Comment: @parseval thats a trick how to write a second differential equations with a system of  first order equations.....